# Can I draw a line using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drawing

I have a web app where I would like the user to draw a line in the following way: When he clicks on **Point1** and he moves the mouse, draw the line from **Point1** to the **current mouse position** and, when clicks to **Point2** draw the final line **from Point1 to Point2**.

How can I do it using jQuery and/or one of its plugins?

Comment: Using html5 canvas you should be able to do this with just an onclick event but I have no experience with canvas myself. All jQuery will do for you is the event binding and getting the mouse position.

Comment: Google is your friend: http://www.amaslo.com/2012/06/drawing-diagonal-line-in-htmlcssjs-with.html

Answer (score 6):

Challenge accepted.

I tried to do it with CSS transforms and a bunch of Math in Javascript - after half an hour I have this:

http://jsfiddle.net/VnDrb/2/

Make 2 clicks into the gray square and a line should be drawn. 
There is still a small bug that draws the line wrong when the angle is > 45 degree. Maybe someone else knows how to fix that. Maybe instead of using Math.asin (arcsinus), use a other trigonometrical function, but I'm really not good at it.
I thought I'd post it even there is a small bug, I think it's a good start for you.

Comment: Doesn't work so well, but it's fun! And well done for a good try!

Comment: Oh, Great man! This is really good, and you spent time to make it. This gave me idea

Answer (score 4):

I've tried a number of different approaches this weekend and the solution that worked best for me is from Adam Sanderson: http://monkeyandcrow.com/blog/drawing_lines_with_css3/

His demo is here: http://monkeyandcrow.com/samples/css_lines/

The core of it is very simple, which is always good.

```
div.line{
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  height: 3px; /* Line width of 3 */
  background: #000; /* Black fill */
}


function createLine(x1,y1, x2,y2){
  var length = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
  var angle  = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
  var transform = 'rotate('+angle+'deg)';

    var line = $('<div>')
      .appendTo('#page')
      .addClass('line')
      .css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'transform': transform
      })
      .width(length)
      .offset({left: x1, top: y1});

  return line;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>You can not do it with jQuery and classic HTML.</s>

1. You can do it using SVG (+svgweb for IE8- http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/ )
   SVG can be dynamically created. jQuery + svgweb are working perfectly, you just need to know how to create SVG nodes and you need only jquerify this nodes. After jquerifiing in most cases used only one method `attr()`
2. You can do it using Raphael http://raphaeljs.com/ (based on SVG and VML)
3. You can do it using Canvas ( http://flashcanvas.net/ for IE8- )

---

For SVG programming will be this way:

1. Moment of creating first point: you create empty line `var Line` (also this points coordinates will be `x1` and `y1`)
2. Then you bind on `mousemove` repaint of `x2`, `y2` properties of Line
3. On `mousedown` after `mousemove` you freeze last line position.

---

**UPDATE**

You can do it with CSS/JS, but main problem is in calculations for IE8-, that has only Matrix filter for transformations.

Comment: Hate to be that guy, but you *could* do it with only JS and HTML. I'm just not good enough at trigonometry to whip up a quick answer. You would need one element with a CSS rotation and a single border.

Comment: And how many problems you will get from filters in IE? It has only Matrix filter for transformations, that have many problems with calculations.

Comment: Also it will be not best performance to animate (I mean change on every mousemove) IE filter

Comment: There are a whole bunch of ways to approach this problem, and I think your answer is good so I upvoted it. I just don't agree with you when you say “You can not do it with jQuery and classic HTML.”

Answer (score 0):

Been using a modified version of this for a while now. Works well.

http://www.ofdream.com/code/css/xline2.php

So on first click, drop and object there as a placeholder div, maybe a little circle, then either keep redrawing a line as they move their mouse, or draw it when they click the second time, using the original placeholder as a guide.

I recently made another helper function for this, because my tool involves moving lines around:

```
function setLinePos(x1, y1, x2, y2, id) {
    if (x2 < x1) {
        var temp = x1;
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = temp;
        temp = y1;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = temp;
    }
    var line = $('#line' + id);
    var length = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
    line.css('width', length + "px");
    var angle = Math.atan((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));
    line.css('top', y1 + 0.5 * length * Math.sin(angle) + "px");
    line.css('left', x1 - 0.5 * length * (1 - Math.cos(angle)) + "px");
    line.css('-moz-transform', "rotate(" + angle + "rad)");
    line.css('-webkit-transform', "rotate(" + angle + "rad)");
    line.css('-o-transform', "rotate(" + angle + "rad)");

 }
```

That is the jquery version, and in this iteration I have no IE requirement so I ignore it. I could be adapted from the original function pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

The class

```
function getXY(evt, element) {
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;
    var scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft;
    var elementLeft = rect.left + scrollLeft;
    var elementTop = rect.top + scrollTop;

    x = evt.pageX - elementLeft;
    y = evt.pageY - elementTop;
    return { x: x, y: y };
}
var LineDrawer = {
    LineHTML: `<div style="cursor: pointer;transform-origin:center; position:absolute;width:200px;height:2px; background-color:blue"></div>`,
    isDown: false,
    pStart: {},
    pCurrent :{},
    containerID: "",
    JLine: {},
    angle: 0,
    afterLineCallback: null,
    Init: function (containerID, afterLineCallback) {
        LineDrawer.containerID = containerID;
        LineDrawer.afterLineCallback = afterLineCallback;
        LineDrawer.JLine = $(LineDrawer.LineHTML).appendTo("#" + LineDrawer.containerID);
        LineDrawer.JLine.css("transform-origin", "top left");
        LineDrawer.JLine.hide();
        //LineDrawer.JLine.draggable({ containment: "#" + LineDrawer.containerID });
        $("#" + LineDrawer.containerID).mousedown(LineDrawer.LineDrawer_mousedown);
        $("#" + LineDrawer.containerID).mousemove(LineDrawer.LineDrawer_mousemove);
        $("#" + LineDrawer.containerID).mouseup(LineDrawer.LineDrawer_mouseup);
    },
    LineDrawer_mousedown: function (e) {
        if (e.target === LineDrawer.JLine[0]) return false;
        LineDrawer.isDown = true;
        let p = LineDrawer.pStart = getXY(e, e.target);
        LineDrawer.JLine.css({ "left": p.x, "top": p.y, "width": 1});
        LineDrawer.JLine.show();
    },
    LineDrawer_mousemove: function (e) {
        if (!LineDrawer.isDown) return;
        LineDrawer.pCurrent = getXY(e, document.getElementById("jim"));
        let w = Math.sqrt(((LineDrawer.pStart.x - LineDrawer.pCurrent.x) * (LineDrawer.pStart.x - LineDrawer.pCurrent.x)) + ((LineDrawer.pStart.y - LineDrawer.pCurrent.y) * (LineDrawer.pStart.y - LineDrawer.pCurrent.y)));
        LineDrawer.JLine.css("width", w - 2);
        LineDrawer.angle = Math.atan2((LineDrawer.pStart.y - LineDrawer.pCurrent.y), (LineDrawer.pStart.x - LineDrawer.pCurrent.x)) * (180.0 / Math.PI);
        //the below ensures that angle moves from 0 to -360
        if (LineDrawer.angle < 0) {
            LineDrawer.angle *= -1;
            LineDrawer.angle += 180;
        }
        else LineDrawer.angle = 180 - LineDrawer.angle;
        LineDrawer.angle *= -1;

        LineDrawer.JLine.css("transform", "rotate(" + LineDrawer.angle + "deg");

    },
    LineDrawer_mouseup: function (e) {
        LineDrawer.isDown = false;
        if (LineDrawer.afterLineCallback == null || LineDrawer.afterLineCallback == undefined) return;
        LineDrawer.afterLine(LineDrawer.angle, LineDrawer.pStart, LineDrawer.pCurrent);
    },
};
```

Usage:

```
var ECApp = {
    start_action: function () {
        LineDrawer.Init("jim", ECApp.afterLine);            
    },
    afterLine(angle, pStart, pEnd) {
        //$("#angle").text("angle : " + angle);
        let disp = "angle = " + angle;
        disp += " Start = " + JSON.stringify(pStart) + " End = " + JSON.stringify(pEnd);
        //alert(disp);
        $("#angle").text("angle : " + disp);
    }
}
$(document).ready(ECApp.start_action);
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
    <div id="jim" style="position:relative;width:1200px;height:800px;background-color:lightblue;">            
    </div>
</div>
```