# Draw a line between two draggable elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, svg, raphael, draggable

I have a series of divs that are draggable upon clicking them. When you release the mouse, the div will animate back into its original position.

I want to be able to draw a straight line between any two of these draggable divs. The line should start at the center of one div and end at the center of the second div. When I click and drag one of the divs, the line should remain connected to both divs, stretching/shrinking as needed dependent upon the amount of space between the two divs. When the mouse is released, the line should still remain connected to the divs.

I have the draggable divs working correctly. I'm just really not sure at all on how to solve for the line drawing portion. Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[this article runs through a fairly complex](http://www.amaslo.com/2012/06/drawing-diagonal-line-in-htmlcssjs-with.html)** way of drawing a line with jquery and some css transforms - personally never tried it but probably worth a look

there's also always canvas but i believe that would probably be even less practical in this instance

**[finally this answer has a few other ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743466/2397883)** including js libraries that could potentially solve your problem